# What might it be? Singular and collective and a leg to stand

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Singular and collective and a leg to stand.
>
> In the correct siblings hands it can leave the land.
>
> For a horse, it's cart, for death, the heart.
>
> It divides and conquers, lives and dies,
>
> Rises up to the skies.

**What might it be?**

Comment: @ Andrew, not collective _pitch_, right?

Comment: @ John, tisn't a pitch. I just mean it can be singular and collective. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wood

Singular and collective

> Wood can denote a single piece of wood or a bunch of pieces.

a leg to stand

> Tables legs are made of wood

In the correct siblings hands it can leave the land.

> The Wright Brothers' plane was made of wood.

For a horse, it's cart

> Horse drawn carts are usually made of wood.

for death, the heart.

> A wooden stake through the heart will cause death

It divides

> room dividers are often made of wood

and conquers

> Siege Engines are often made of wood, and are used in war to conquer.

lives and dies

> Wood comes from trees, which live and die

Rises up to the skies.

> Trees grow upwards toward the sky

Comment: Good work, you got it! :) Divides was fences and "conquers" was sort of conkers.